# Assign allocator to field - should I create default allocator as a global variable?

Tags: c++, singleton, c++14, allocator

My game **engine** has 2 allocators : heap and stack.

```
class GameEngine{public:
    Allocator* heap;  //<-- a custom allocator class
    Allocator* stack;
}
```

Today, I want to create a class **Car** that need the heap allocator.

```
class Car{
    MyArray<Car*> nearEnemyCache; //<-- my custom storage, need allocator
};
```

Thus, to create a car instance, I snatch the heap allocator from **engine** and assign it to **car**.

```
class CarFactory{
    GameEngine* gameEngine;
    Car* createCar(){
        Car* car=new Car();
        car->nearEnemyCache.setAllocator( gameEngine->heap );
        return car;
    }
};
```

Here is the diagram :-

[image]

### Problem

If the `car` class grows and has a lot of field that need allocator :-

```
class Car{
    MyArray<Car*> nearEnemyCache; //<-- need allocator
    class A{    };
    MyArray<A> as;  //<--- need allocator
    class B{}; 
    MyUnorderMap<B> bs; //<--- need allocator
};
```

I will have to assign allocator to them, one by one manually.
It leads to dirty code.

```
Car* createCar(){
    Car* car=new Car();
    car->nearEnemyCache.setAllocator( gameEngine->heap );
    car->as.setAllocator( gameEngine->heap );
    car->bs.setAllocator( gameEngine->heap );   //<-- so dirty & tedious
    return car;
}
```

## My Poor Solutions

Both solution are using global variable as **default allocator** either directly or indirectly.
I believe using global variable is generally a bad practice.

### 1. global default allocator

Set global allocator at the beginning of program and use it as default 
e.g.  :-

```
Allocator* defaultAllocator;
template<class T>MyArray{
    Allocator* allocator=defaultAllocator;
    //... other stuffs
}
int main(){
    //create "gameEngine"
    defaultAllocator=gameEngine->heap;
    // start game
}
```

### 2. global game-engine variable.

```
GameEngine* defaultGameEngine;
template<class T> class MyArray{
    Allocator* allocator=defaultGameEngine->heap;
    //... other stuffs
}
int main(){
    //create "gameEngine"
    defaultGameEngine=gameEngine;
    // start game
}
```

**Similar questions :-**

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56025/is-it-acceptable-to-have-a-global-singleton-engine-class-in-an-entity-component  : states that global variable is bad.  The situation is very similar to mine, but its alternative lead to my problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you are rolling out your own containers and not using `std::` utilities? Fine for study purposes.

Comment: @DeiDei  In a few testing tiny games, I found that mine are slightly-to-moderately faster than `std::`.

Comment: Are the allocators really determined at runtime? Templating containers (and the classes that use them) on the allocator type to avoid virtual function calls in every allocation seems sensible performance-wise. And you could still decide at runtime between the two in your factory.

Comment: Also, why not pass the allocator to the class constructor (and then further pass it as [optional?] argument to the containers)?

Comment: @Max Langhof  :  I know that in `nearEnemyCache` always use heap allocator (not stack).   Instance of allocator is determined at run-time, though.    .... I use virtual function for simplicity. I probably change to template later.  Thank.  ..... Passing allocator to `Car()` constructor = move dirty-code to the `Car` class.   The total dirty-ness of my code would still be unchanged.

Comment: Is there only ever one heap allocator and one stack allocator (and one game engine)? In that case the singleton pattern sounds like your solution.

Comment: @Max Langhof   Yes, I can't imagine any use case that there is > 1 stack/heap/engine.  However, the internet always denounce the singleton pattern.  (ex.https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56025/is-it-acceptable-to-have-a-global-singleton-engine-class-in-an-entity-component)  If my game engine is global variable, many things will become easy.   I doubt if there are some serious disadvantage to make game-engine a singleton.  It is a one-way scary trip.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot possibly imagine a case where there is more than one stack/heap/engine, then this is probably best expressed as a singleton.

This could also mesh with templating your containers: If you *know* your car will only ever use heap allocation, then having a member like `MyArray<Car*, HeapAllocator> nearEnemyCache;` will allow the container to just access the corresponding singleton (and will hide that part from your "real" logic, so no more dirtyness in there).

```
template<class T, class DefaultAlloc = ChosenAtRuntimeAlloc>
class MyArray
{
public:
    MyArray() : _allocator(singleton<DefaultAlloc>::get())
    {
    }

    void setAllocator(Allocator* alloc)
    {
        _allocator = alloc;
    }

private:
    Allocator* _allocator;
};
```

Then you can set it at runtime if you want to, but don't have to do that if you know it at compile-time. The `ChosenAtRuntimeAlloc` class would just throw an exception when asked to allocate (`"Must set an allocator at runtime before allocating!"`).

If you *always* know which allocators your containers will use (i.e. you'd never have to default the second template parameter) then you could even eliminate all virtual functions from your allocators and instead allow the compiler to inline all those. That's basically the way the standard library containers do it.

Comment: Thank.  I love your `singleton<DefaultAlloc>::get()`.   It is somehow similar as described in https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/blog/optimizing-tarray-usage-for-performance.  Hmm, singleton/global seems to be the best way to manage allocator.